# Crystal Report export to MS access

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports, export

I want to export a data of crystal report into Ms Access as report has almost 2 million records and Ms Excel does not support that much data. 
Is there any plugin of Crystal report or something to export data without changing my code (as making live the updated code has to go through long process). I am working in Dotnet 2.0 (VS2005)

Comment: What do you mean by 2 million records? Access (ACE) will allow 2 gigabytes minus the space needed for system objects - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-specifications-HP005186808.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Crystal Reports does not have a Microsoft-Access-export library.  You will need to use CSV or TTX.

A better: why do you need to export 2M records?  If this is really a requirement, it would be more efficient to do this from the database directly.

Comment: I just had wanted not to change the code as it requires a lot of documentation and explanations in my organization. But it seems there is no other option so I have to write routines to export data to Ms Access.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "a data of crystal report"? Crystal Report does not hold data. It just has the ability to connect to a database. Thus, it could be smarter to use ms-access to connect directly to this very same database. Once you're connected, transferring the data to ms-access will be a piece of cake ...

Comment: Yes for sure a report does not keep data, but it has data which is presented and I was referring to that. Export data that is presented in a report.

Comment: so you should be able to check the connection, the table and the sql query used for your report. Copy and arrange it into Access and you'll be done.